# Hovering mouse over something in Blender shows python code, but how does one use it?

Tags: python, video-sequence-editor

I know the trick of hovering my mouse over the function I want to perform to reveal its corresponding python code, but i'm not sure how to use this code, for example from vse: **menu playback>audio scrubbing** and which bit to use:

```
Scene.use_audio_scrub
bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].use_audio_scrub
```

I have also looked [here](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_77a_release/bpy.types.Scene.html#bpy.types.Scene.use_audio_scrub), but am none the wiser.

I tried placing the code in the console but got the error message:

```
>>> bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].use_audio_scrub = true
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'true' is not defined
```

Comment: Could you clarify your question. Right now, I only read "how to use".

Comment: Open a Python Console Editor (or switch a currently opened view to such one) and paste the code there to read it or assign a value to this boolean (like true or false) to set it...

Comment: Related: https://www.blendernation.com/2013/04/18/tutorial-automating-tasks-in-blender-with-python-scripting-2/, https://www.blendernation.com/2016/10/21/introduction-to-blender-scripting-for-python-programmers-talk-at-pycon-israel-2016/, https://www.blendernation.com/2016/09/17/blender-python-tutorial-automation-operations/, https://www.blendernation.com/2014/11/24/using-ipython-with-blender/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because `true` is not a python keyword. You meant to use `True` (capitalized).

Use `bpy.context.scene`, this gets the active scene instead of a scene name "Scene".

The code usually refers to the operation or the datablock, which the button or UI controls changes or calls.

The following code works.

```
import bpy

# Next two lines assign absolute values ("True" / "False")
# bpy.context.scene.use_audio_scrub = True
# bpy.context.scene.use_audio_scrub = False

# method changing the use_audio_scrub state
def Custom_Toggle_Audio_Scrub():
    bpy.context.scene.use_audio_scrub = not bpy.context.scene.use_audio_scrub

# call and execute the method
Custom_Toggle_Audio_Scrub()
```